# Batch file - Find services and stop them

Tags: batch-file, service

Here is my code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%H IN ('sc query ^| find "SERVICE_NAME"') do (
  SET service_name=%%H
  SET start_name=!service_name:~0,5!
  IF !start_name!.==redis. (
    net stop !service_name!
    sc config !service_name! start= demand
  )
)
```

This works fine. It finds all services with the name staring by "redis", stops them and then change their starting type to Manual.

However, if I change the `sc query` to `sc query state= all`, it's not working anymore, I get the error saying that the service does not exist... The command works in a prompt window however.

The reason I want to have `state= all` is to change the starting type of the services that are found, even if they are not currently running (if not running, they are not displayed in the `sc query` command).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` sign in `state= all` needs to be escaped since it's inside of the `FOR` loop.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%H IN ('sc query state^= all ^| find "SERVICE_NAME"') do (
  SET service_name=%%H
  SET start_name=!service_name:~0,5!
  IF !start_name!.==redis. (
    net stop !service_name!
    sc config !service_name! start= demand
  )
)
```

Comment: I knew there was something very simple I didn't know about. Thanks :)